# What options do I have regarding indexing PDFs while running on Elasticsearch 1.x and Spring Data 1.x, especially if I want to upgrade?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

We have a new requirement on our Elasticsearch - to index PDFs. We are still running on Elasticsearch version 1.x (and Spring Data 1.3.4).

I look at the documentation for Elasticsearch 5 and they have new ways of supporting PDFs in 5 (and I would like to upgrade).

So given all this the way I see it I have the following options:

1. Sit tight and wait for Spring Data to support Elasticsearch 5. This is viable if it is not too far away (please let us know, Spring Data and Elasticsearch dev) although given the business urgency on this feature I don't think I have much leeway
2. Move off Spring data altogether - this is not as crazy as it sounds as given the complexity of my queries I don't use the Spring Data repositories a great deal. I do however use them for inserting data. I would have to provide my own implementations of the current repository interfaces. It would be work but I wouldn't need to wait for any one and would not need to use any outdated plugins etc
3. Somehow run on Elasticsearch 5 with Spring Data 2.x/3.x. Will this work at all? Chances are it probably won't even startup.
4. Upgrade my Elasticsearch/Spring Data to 2.x and use the "old" way of indexing PDFs.

Which option is the best way to go?